# Exception running application LoginApp.LoginApplication

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm fairly new to coding and was just following a Youtube video and I'm getting the below error when trying to run my simple program.

```
    package LoginApp;

    import javafx.application.Application;

    import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

    import javafx.scene.Parent;

    import javafx.scene.Scene;

    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class LoginApplication extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage)throws Exception{

    Parent root = (Parent) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("NHL Database System");
    stage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Screenshot:

How can I fix this? I looks like the code is completely fine. Something with configuring IntelliJ IDEA or something happened. I'm following this Youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h1rYlMrvNyE) and only made it 10 minutes in before I couldn't get the window to pop-up when running the program.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgeyt.png): [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgeyt.png)

Comment: don't post screenshots. copy paste the exception text.

Comment: [mcve] please..